# Ember trigger action on wrapper component

Tags: ember.js

I have a wrapper component that has an action that needs to be triggered from within, but I can't get rid of this:

```
    {{#wrapper-component as |wrapper|}}
        <button {{action 'wrapper.myAction'}}
    {{/wrapper-component}}
```

the above is the template of "componentA"; when I click the button I get an error saying that componentA does not have an action handler for "wrapper.myAction"; I can't get why it looks for the action on componentA instead of wrapper-component first.
of course "myAction" is defined in "actions" on "wrapper-component";
the wrapper component has this template:

```
{{yield (hash myAction=(action 'myAction'))}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<button {{action 'wrapper.myAction'}}
```

with this:

```
<button onclick={{action wrapper.myAction}}
```

---

please make sure you understand the difference between ember actions and closure actions.